# I get invalid need: expected Wait, have None in my Bot code

Tags: botframework

I get "invalid need: expected Wait, have None" exception in RootDialog, MessageReceivedAsync method's context.Forward line. Why could this be happening? what correction should I make? Please find my code below.

I use -C#, Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft Bot Framework, Bot emulator. This is for Web Chat.

MessageController

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
        }
        else
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            var greeting = activity.CreateReply("Hi! I'm Cmon. Enter the Id of the Employee you want to know about.");
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(greeting);
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

RootDialog -

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        try
        {
            if (message.Text != null)
            {
                await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), null, message,CancellationToken.None);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong :-(");
        }
    }
```

DirectoryDialog -

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;
        var query = DirectoryQuery.Parse(message.Text);
        await context.PostAsync($"Searching for {query.SearchKey}...");

        try
        {
            await SearchEmployee(context, query);
        }
        catch (FormCanceledException ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong :-(");
        }
    }

    private async Task SearchEmployee(IDialogContext context, DirectoryQuery searchQuery)
    {
        DirectoryDal dal = new DirectoryDal();
        DataSet ds = dal.GetEmployeeSearch(searchQuery.SearchKey);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 & ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder employeeSearchMessageBuilder = new StringBuilder(100);
//do something with data table data
            var employeeSearchReply = context.MakeMessage();
            employeeSearchReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
            employeeSearchReply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Markdown;
            employeeSearchReply.Text = employeeSearchMessageBuilder.ToString();
            await context.PostAsync(employeeSearchReply);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing null here:

```
await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), null, message,CancellationToken.None);
```

you are breaking the dialog chain. You have to define your Resume method.

The Troubleshooting section of the documentation has a good section about that, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-3.0#im-using-the-bot-builder-sdk-for-net-how-can-i-troubleshoot-issues-with-my-bot):

> **Ensure all dialog methods end with a plan to handle the next message.**
>
> All `IDialog` methods should complete with `IDialogStack.Call`,
> `IDialogStack.Wait`, or I`DialogStack.Done`. These `IDialogStack` methods
> are exposed through the `IDialogContext` that is passed to every `IDialog`
> method. Calling `IDialogStack.Forward` and using the system prompts
> through the `PromptDialog` static methods will call one of these methods
> in their implementation.

Comment: I added a method in my RootDialog `private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }` also, I changed context.Forward to ` await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message,CancellationToken.None);` I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help more by guessing your code. Provide your complete implementation of message controller, RootDialog and DirectoryDialog

Answer (score 0):

```
context.wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

at the end of MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result) method of Root Dialog.

and

```
context.done(true);
```

at the end of StartAsync method of DirectoryDialog or within both try and catch block

Comment: On doing this I get "invalid need: expected Wait, have Call" Error in the StartAsync of DirectoryDialog.

Comment: Can you post the modified code, I hope they are in the right place

Comment: Also, on implementing this solution along with Nicolas's suggestion (Removing null from context.forward of RootDialog and replacing it with Resume method) leads to infinite response of my desired result along with the context.post async message of **ResumeAfterOptionDialog** method of the RootDialog.

Comment: Oh, please add a method name instead of null and have context.wait(messageReceivedasync) in it

Comment: DirectoryDialog-`public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;
            var query = DirectoryQuery.Parse(message.Text);
            await context.PostAsync($"Searching for {query.SearchKey}...");
            
                await SearchEmployee(context, query);
               
            context.Done(true);
        }`

Comment: RootDialog-`public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
           
                if (message.Text != null)
                {
                    await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);
                }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }`

Comment: public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        try
        {
            if (message.Text != null)
            {
                await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), null, message,CancellationToken.None);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong ;context.done(true);
        }
    }

Comment: Remove null in forward, add a method name within which just have context.wait(messagereceivedasync)

Comment: I made the modifications suggested by you, removed null and added a method name which has just context.wait(messagereceivedasync). it leads to infinite response of my desired result.

Comment: RootDialog -`public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        { var message = await result;
            try
            {
                if (message.Text != null)
                {
                    await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message,CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong");
                context.Done(true);
            }
        }`

Comment: Add context.wait(messagereceivedasync) at theend of messagereceivedasync just before last closing brace

Comment: It is still returning infinite results. Just to be sure that we are on the same page, in RootDialog messagereceivesasync method, I have context.wait just before the ending  and context.done in the catch block under context.postasync. Also, the context.forward now has a Reponse method which also contains context.wait inside the response method. In DirectoryDialog startAsync I have Context.Done(true) just before closing the brace. Could this be because of the Context.Done in the DirectoryDialog? - just guessing.

Comment: MessageReceivedAsync of RootDialog-`public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>result){var message = await result;try{if (message.Text != null){
                    await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message,CancellationToken.None);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong");
                context.Done(true);
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }`

Comment: context.done is meant to end the current dialog and remove from top of the stack and go to next method at top of the stack

Comment: Oh, I just got it. Inside DirectoryDialog start async, put context.Done inside try bock as well as in catch block

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by making the following modifications to my DirectoryDialog.

DirectoryDialog code -

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;
        var query = DirectoryQuery.Parse(message.Text);
        await context.PostAsync($"Searching for {query.SearchKey}...");
        try
        {
            //await SearchEmployee(context, query);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        catch (FormCanceledException ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong :-(");
        }
    }
```

RootDialog code -

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        try
        {
            if (message.Text != null)
            {
                await context.Forward(new DirectoryDialog(), ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message,CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Oops! Something went wrong");
        }

     finally{
        context.Done(true);
    }
    } 

    private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
                }
```

Thank you Tanmoy and Nicolas for helping! :)

Comment: I forgor to add the DirectoryDialog's MessageReceivedAsync method. Here -`public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;
            var query = DirectoryQuery.Parse(message.Text);
            await SearchEmployee(context, query);
        }`